# NUMPY: Question about specifying structured dtype alignment

Tags: numpy

I have looked around for an answer to this, but havent found exactly what I need. I want to be able to create a structured dtype representing a C struct with non-default alignment. An example struct:

```
struct __attribute__((aligned(8))) float2
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

I can create dtype with two floats easily enough:

```
float2_dtype = np.dtype( [ ( 'x', 'f4' ), ( 'y', 'f4' ) ], align=True )
```

but the alignment for this dtype (float2_dtype.alignment) will be 4. This means that if I pack this dtype into another structured dtype I will get alignment errors. What I would really like to do is

```
float2_dtype.alignment = 8 
# gives AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

or

```
float2_dtype = np.dtype( [ ( 'x', 'f4' ), ( 'y', 'f4' ) ], align=True, alignment=8 )
# Invalid keyword argument for dtype()
```

Is there a way to to this? I apologize if I have missed an obvious solution to this issue -- I have grepped around the internet with no success.

Comment: I suspect the `offset` parameter will help, but I don't know what `alignment` does in `c`

Comment: A broad internet search is only as good as your search terms.  I'd focus on numpy docs - dtype and structured arrays.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#offsets-and-alignment talks about dtype alignment.  You got the keyword error because you did not read the numpy docs, `dtype(dtype, align=False, copy=False)`.

Comment: @hpaulj I know that the keyword argument is invalid -- I am saying that this is the functionality I *wish* I could use.  I have read over the offsets and alignment docs for numpy thoroughly  and I have ready many varying stack overflow posts, blog posts, etc found by searching search terms such as  structured dtype alignment.

Comment: And yes, offset can be used to manually align fields in the general case (this is the workaround I am using for now), but this is not really a feasible approach in general as it requires users to fully layout potentially complicated C structts, matching all padding and alignment rules.

Comment: Playing around with `dtype`, I find that I can get a `8` `alignment` if `align=True` and at least one field is 'f8' (or 'I8').  I don't see a way of specifying alignment otherwise.  It's taking the alignment from the largest field

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative syntax for `dtype`, which allows to force specific `itemsize`. Say, one want to make array of 3-element subarrays, having `unsigned short` (`uint16_t`) element type, but want it to be aligned on 4-byte address boundary (it is required for, say, vertex attributes in OpenGL).

```py
import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype({"names": ["POSITION"], "formats": [("u2", 3)], "itemsize": 8})
assert dt["POSITION"].base.itemsize == 2  # u2
assert dt["POSITION"].itemsize == 6  # (3,)u2
assert dt.itemsize == 8  # (3,)u2, V2
```

Now when an array of `dtype=dt` is written to a file it is possible to manually align file cursor to 4-byte boundary in advance, then to write the array:

```py
>>> with open("/tmp/1", "wb") as f:
...     # make some writes for bad alignment
...     f.write(np.zeros(1, np.dtype("u1")))
...     assert f.tell() == 1
...
...     # add padding to 4-byte alignment
...     f.write(np.empty(4 - (f.tell() % 4), np.uint8).tobytes())
...
...     # write payload starting at 4-byte aligned offset
...     assert f.tell() % 4 == 0
...     payload = np.full(100, 65535, dt)
...     f.write(payload.tobytes())
... 
1
3
800
>>>
```

Now if blob is loaded into properly aligned memory it is guaranteed, that array `payload` (100 x 0xFFFF values) will begin at 4-byte boundary.